# CSS Overflow Settings - Simulate Entering A Long Equation In Calculator

Tags: css, overflow

My project is a calculator. I am trying to simulate entering a long mathematical equation that is longer than the display width.  I want the left side of the equation to scroll off the screen when it gets too long.

Example:
50+200x25/43-500x60 (this is the width of the calculator screen)
**50+200x**25/43-500x60-45x200 (the part in BOLD should scroll off screen)

The equation is within a paragraph tag. I am unsure how to set CSS for the following:

```
#lcd {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr
}
```

I thought the direction should be "rtl" but it doesn't work.  The operator ends up on the wrong side of the number.)

Comment: Can you please add code snippet that can be executed?

Comment: The link below from Obsidian Age is good but just add this line to the CSS and it works:   "unicode-bidi: plaintext;"

Answer (score 1):

In order to scroll off to the left side of the screen, you have to use `direction: rtl` instead of `direction : ltr`.

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/8seb4f0v/).

I'm not sure what you mean about the operator ending up on the wrong side of the number, as there is no 'operator' per se; the entire thing is simply a text string, and does not get modified in any way other than some of the string not being visible on the screen.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It mostly works.  But when it's <p id="lcd">50+</p> the output is +50.  I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: I think I got it.  If I add this line, "unicode-bidi: plaintext;", then it works.